# FTP software which can enforce download limits

Tags: ftp

I need to download from an FTP site.

It has limits such as 1000 files per hour.

Is there FTP software where you can create rules that will download to these type of specifications? So the FTP software will stop downloading and wait an hour, then keep downloading?

Comment: How many files are you downloading if you're hitting a 1000 files per hour limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `wget` recursive download ability, or give it a list of files to get or both, you can use its `--wait` option to give the same effect.

`--wait=4` will add a pause of four seconds between each file meaning that you could get at most 900 files per hour (you would only get the 900/hour if each file transfer was instant though). If you know that each file will take more than 0.6 seconds to download you could use `--wait=3` which would be faster, obviously, but could break the 1000 files/hour limit (if each file transfer were instantaneous you could get 1200/hour).

`wget` is in the standard repositories for just about all Linux variants (and is often installed by default) and is available for Windows and other OSs too. It is a command line tool but there are many GUI front-end wrappers for it if you prefer (I can't recommend one personally as I always use wget from the command line).

Comment: Trying this out, seems to work perfectly for what I need, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The [ncftp Client](http://www.ncftp.com/) can be used in combination with a shell script to count files per hour.